# Active directory member vs memberOf

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm confused between `member` and `memberOf` attributes.
Let's say that i have group called "ABX", the group has the following attributes values:

1. member: `cn="foo", OU="Groups"`
2. memberOf: `cn="test", OU="Groups"`

What is the child groups of ABX? is it foo or test?

Comment: foo is child of ABX, test is parent of ABX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `member` means that this object is a member of this provided (which is viewed now) group.
2. `memberOf` means that this object is a member of a group.

So a group can be a member of a group => nested groups.

In your case: `foo` is a member of `ABX` and `ABX` is a member of the group `test`.